# BTC Transfer from One Exchange Vendor to Other Exchange Vendor

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

It's my first time doing transfer with BTC. I have read from some articles that if you send BTC with low transfer fee it will be stuck in the network and the status is 'unconfirmed'.

I was sending ~0.049 BTC from one merchant to another merchant (BTCMarkets to Binance). I'm not sure how it performs but somehow my transfer was joined with someone else transfer. The other transfer was confirmed but my transfer is still unconfirmed. I also have no idea how to 'control' the transfer fee since I only paid the withdrawal fee from BTCMarkets. Below is the tx for the transfer. The ~0.0049 BTC was my transfer which is still unconfirmed.

https://blockchain.info/tx/e75f48c3fa06de6198fc0fbac0f2a2eadcdd6608ca572757015d45cdba6c1f1a

Can anyone help how to un-stuck or reverse or change the status to 'confirm' for my transfer? Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I've marked this as a duplicate of a 'my transaction isn't confirming' question, there is a lot of good info if you look at the answers there.

One additional note: when sending from one exchange to another, you do not decide the fee. The exchange controls the keys that spend the coins, so they will set the fee for you. If you control the keys of your coins yourself, then you can choose the fees when you spend your bitcoins.

Exchanges can choose to 'batch withdrawals', which means they will send multiple withdrawals to customers as a single transaction with multiple outputs. Batching a transaction allows the sender to pay less fees than if each transaction was sent individually.

Comment: Thanks Chytrik for the info. One more question, so why the other transfer was confirmed (spent) and my transfer is not confirmed yet (unspent)? The fee is 442.478 sat/B which i believe is high enough and for both transfers. Is it because the other BTC value is higher (0.45 BTC) than my BTC value (0.049 BTC)?